# Store not reloading in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, store, extjs6.5

I am working on a display where I need to bind a combobox but its not reloading with latest data.
There is only one call to database and after that its using existing store from cache. How to make it reload from database every-time(or at least every-time when we reopen the display). Below is the code.

```
//store
Ext.define('NetworkStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'NetworkStore',
    fields: ['Id', 'value'],
    storeId: 'NetworkStore', 
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
        actionMethods: { create: "POST", read: "GET", update: "POST", destroy: "POST" },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencode' },
        limitParam: false,
        startParam: false,
        pageParam: false,
        extraParams: {
            Style: 1
        },
        url: 'url',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

xtype: 'combo',
name: 'NetworkIDList',
store: Ext.create('NetworkStore').load({
                    params: {
                        Style: 3
                    }
                }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we pass store as given below it will always get store from db not from cache.

```
  store: {
            type: 'NetworkStore',
            proxy: {
                    extraParams: {
                        Style: 3
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The offical docs in `lastQuery` offer:

```
    listeners: {
        beforequery: function (qe) {
            delete qe.combo.lastQuery;
        }
    }
```

here is the full soure:

```
/**
 * @property {String} lastQuery
 * The value of the match string used to filter the store. Delete this property to force
 * a requery. Example use:
 *
 *     var combo = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
 *         ...
 *         queryMode: 'remote',
 *         listeners: {
 *             // delete the previous query in the beforequery event or set
 *             // combo.lastQuery = null (this will reload the store the next time it expands)
 *             beforequery: function(qe){
 *                 delete qe.combo.lastQuery;
 *             }
 *         }
 *     });
 *
 * To make sure the filter in the store is not cleared the first time the ComboBox trigger
 * is used configure the combo with `lastQuery=''`. Example use:
 *
 *     var combo = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
 *         ...
 *         queryMode: 'local',
 *         triggerAction: 'all',
 *         lastQuery: ''
 *     });
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the desired logic to the list `expand` event handler.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/327t)

```
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'NetworkIDList',
            listeners: {
                expand: function () {
                    this.getStore().load()
                }
            },
            store: Ext.create('NetworkStore').load({
                params: {
                    Style: 3
                }
            })
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @pvlt, but here we are already loading store by passing it to store property, then again we are reloading it on expand. I think we should avoid reloading/passing store at expand.

Answer (score 0):

```
remoteFilter: true
```

true if want to load datas from  the server side on each expand of combobox, 
false if you want to load data  locally after once it is loaded.

if remoteFilter property is not set in the store it defaults to false.
soo setting this property to true might solve the issue

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert your desire to a systematic logic.

> "at least every-time when we reopen the display"

Like the following logic:

1. Listen to the widget's event, which means to "when we reopen the display"
2. Reload the widget's store

```
    {
       xtype: 'combo',
       name: 'NetworkIDList',
       store: Ext.create('NetworkStore').load({
                    params: {
                        Style: 3
                    }
                }),
      //Add this:
       afterRender: function(){
            //Just do this to load the store
            this.getStore().load();
       }
     }
```

afterRender is one of sample listeners which can be declared as a method. There are many other event listeners  you can use to place your code to load the widget's store again and again as you want.

see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Widget.html#method-afterRender

and .load() is the ProxyStore's method which can be used to first load manually or reload the store.

see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.data.ProxyStore.html#method-load

Hope it help.